# Python install module locally without root rights

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pip, installation

I would like to know what is the best way to install locally python3 modules on a cluster where you don't have the root rights. Python3 is not currently installed on it.

I already downloaded/installed the latest python3 version from source. How can I:

- Install a module from source to a place which will be found by this python3
- Install a module using the pip of this python3 to a place which will be found by this python3

Comment: https://gist.github.com/saurabhshri/46e4069164b87a708b39d947e4527298

Comment: Please follow the instructions in this link!

Comment: If you installed Python somewhere writable, its normal site-packages should be somewhere writable as well, which means you can just use `pip3 install spam` or `python3 -m pip install spam` (or however you normally run your Python, the same thing with `-m pip` as arguments).